# How can i set values for Billing information and companies in ics(iCalendar) file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, icalendar

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20120112T075256Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20120112T075256Z
DTSTAMP:20120112T075256Z
UID:00U90000002N691EAC
SUMMARY:testin
ORGANIZER;RSVP=TRUE;CN=Perumal;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;ROLE=CHAIR:mailto:perumalsamy.subbian@gmail.com
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:20110705T023000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:20110705T033000
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
```

within `VEVENT` how can I set values for billing information and companies?

Answer (score 0):

if you are set on having billing information in the ics, you might want to consider the following property:

x-param     = x-name "=" param-value *("," param-value)
     ; A non-standard, experimental parameter.

note that: the rfc5545 also states "Applications MUST ignore x-param and iana-param values they don't recognize."